# Google Big Query outter Join to UNNEST

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with several arrays of objects ...

I can query the objects using the UNNEST function , however this returns an inner join between the table and its own object ... can I code for an outer join

''' 
    select k.*, emails.email 
    from `dataset.mytable` as k, 
          UNNEST(emails) as emails 
'''

only getting records that have non-null in the emails field.

Comment: You need to provide a few more detais so the community can help you better, Show your data, and a complete example of what you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: The `,` is short for `cross join`, hope that clears things up

Answer (score 3):

Use LEFT JOIN instead as in below example

```
SELECT k.*, emails.email FROM dataset.mytable AS k LEFT JOIN UNNEST(emails) as emails
```